# Preguntas por cada problema que tengan en su proyecto

Tags: discusión

En lo personal, me he topado con muchos usuarios (No nuevos) que se truncan con algo en lo que estén trabajando, y recurren a SO para resolver dicho inconveniente, haciendo una pregunta, lo cual está bien.

Pero, ¿Qué pasa cuando ese comportamiento es muy recurrente?

Algunos usuarios simplemente no se toman la molestia de investigar o tratar de resolver errores cuando aparecen, ni aprender de preguntas anteriores, por muy simples que sean.

Para ellos, **cada error nuevo implica una pregunta nueva** y siento que no debería ser así, independientemente de lo bien estructurada que esté la pregunta. Porque, al final, cada pregunta hecha se torna muy personalizada.

- ¿Se debería hacer algo al respecto en este tipo de comportamientos?
- ¿No es un comportamiento que fomenta el desinterés a investigar por
  cuenta propia?

Comment: Cuando detecto esos casos, simplemente los ignoro. Tampoco hay nada que se pueda hacer al respecto: es obvio que quién pregunta no destaca por sus cualidades de análisis y entendimiento.

Comment: Candid Moe, quien pregunta es quien, precisamente, muestra interés: todos empezamos preguntamos (por eso llegamos aquí muchos) y lo seguimos haciendo (por eso seguimos muchos aquí). Entiendo que quisiste decir: quien pregunta, aprende; quien pregunta dos veces, no aprendió nada.

Answer (score 5):

Es muy complicado pienso yo, ya que muchas veces te topas con preguntas así y te tomaría mucho tiempo verificar si el usuario hizo una pregunta anterior con el mismo formato (sin investigar nada), por lo que en mi opinión personal procedo a responder a tus preguntas:

> ¿Se debería hacer algo al respecto en este tipo de comportamientos?

Pues según, normalmente cuando veo este tipo de preguntas que a simple vista se nota que no hubo investigación por detrás las marco como *"Baja calidad"*, ya que lo más común es que este tipo de usuarios no agregan código y la mayoría de las veces no saben explicar bien su problema o simplemente no agregan los detalles necesarios.

En todo caso si están bien planteadas (y se note que no hubo investigación) personalmente intento pasar de largo (aunque a veces me gana la ambición de obtener uno que otro puntillo), pienso que algún buen samaritano siempre ayudará (lo que tampoco esta mal según yo, ya que la finalidad es siempre ayudar cuando la pregunta esté correctamente formulada).

> ¿No es un comportamiento que fomenta el desinterés a investigar por cuenta propia?

Claro que si lo fomenta, ya que hay muchos errores que simplemente con *traducirlos* se tiene una luz muy clara de lo que sucede incluso el cómo resolver el error, incluso les tomaría menos tiempo traducir el error y ver cual es el problema que venir al sitio y formular su pregunta, pero desgraciadamente creo que esto seguirá ocurriendo y es muy complicado poder controlarlo, es la razón por la que varias preguntas quedan abiertas, simplemente porque la respuesta se encuentra en los comentarios que muchas veces dejamos en lugar de responder porque la pregunta *"No amerita una respuesta"* por la extensión de la misma.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Concuerdo contigo, sería muy complicado dar con semejanzas y/o frecuencia en las preguntas que alguien haga para dar con ello. Y quizá debería hacer lo mismo que tú, no darle mucha importancia si me topo con eso, y simplemente pasar de largo.